# How to loop through key/value object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, iteration, key-value

```
var user = {};
```

now I want to create a `setUsers()` method that takes a key/value pair object and initializes the `user` variable.

```
setUsers = function(data) {     
   // loop and init user    
}
```

where data is like:

```
234: "john", 23421: "smith", ....
```

Comment: How an older question can be duplicated from a newer one?

Comment: @PauloCoghi The mods were apparently drunk, nevermind...

Comment: They chose the one with more votes. It's also written a little better. And it's got more answers with more votes. Makes sense to keep that one over this one.

Comment: The data model is objects of a object list `{{},..}`. When would I use this one instead of an array of objects `[{},..]` ? ok, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31470302/1705829) is the answer, welcome to SO;).

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Beware of properties inherited from the object's prototype (which could happen if you're including any libraries on your page, such as older versions of Prototype). You can check for this by using the object's `hasOwnProperty()` method. This is generally a good idea when using `for...in` loops:

```
var user = {};

function setUsers(data) {
    for (var k in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
           user[k] = data[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without a for in loop? I'm worried about speed through large key value pairs (and I know that Crockford isn't a fan from using JSLint, but I'm not sure of his reasoning). Is there a reason to worry about these things?

Comment: @streetlight: It depends on the environment. If you can rely on having ECMAScript 5 (all modern browsers do, as does Node.js), you have options such as [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). If you need to support IE <= 8, for example, you're stuck with `for...in`.

Answer (score 104):

```
for (var key in data) {
    alert("User " + data[key] + " is #" + key); // "User john is #234"
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Something like this:

```
setUsers = function (data) {
    for (k in data) {
        user[k] = data[k];
    }
}
```