# Indexing through JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to index through a JSON list in JavaScript but I'm having quite a lot of trouble getting it to work.

I have tried indexing through the values of each JSON item but it's not outputting what I want. I think I can get it to work but that would be with an extra unnecessary for loop level. Here is my JSON: https://pastebin.com/iYmaA4c5. If you think it would be better to reformat the JSON then that might help too.

```
function output_json(data) {
    var i, j, k;
    for (i=0; i<Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        group_=Object.values(data)[i];
        for (j=0; j<Object.keys(group_).length; j++) {
            person=Object.values(group_)[j];
            person_id=Object.keys(person)[0];
            console.log(person_id);
            for (k=0; k<Object.keys(person).length; k++) {
                person_info=Object.values(person)[k][0];
                console.log(person_info);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to print out the id, and then the name, registration 1, registration 2, week and half_term for each id. At the moment it prints like this:

> HA09_000
>
> {name: "Wyatt Feldt", registration_1: "R", registration_2: "R", week: 0, half_term: 1}

But I want it to print like this for every single one:

> HA09_000
>
> Wyatt Feldt
>
> R
>
> R
>
> 0
>
> 1

Here is some Pseudo Code for what I would like to achieve:

```
FOR GROUP IN DATA:
    FOR PERSON IN GROUP:
        PRINT(PERSON.ID)
        FOR INFO IN PERSON:
            PRINT(INFO)
```

Thanks.

EDIT: This is the function I am using to retrieve the data:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/data.json", function(data) {
    output_json(data);
});
```

Comment: If you need `Object.keys()` then it's not [JSON](http://json.org) but an object -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: @Andreas Okay thanks, but how does that help me solve it?

Comment: Don't you want to learn something that can make your life easier in the future, or that will straighten out a wrong understanding (because strings and objects are completely different)?

Comment: @Andreas Yes of course, but it would be nice to learn it in a way that helps me better understand how to get a solution to my problem.

Comment: Are you missing a closing bracket } on your for loop/function?

Comment: @Sarah Yes, I pasted it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @J P No probs. I added an answer for your problem :) I found some useful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958841/how-to-loop-through-key-value-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two useful ideas:  (1) **objects**:  if this is going to be a real system someday, and the data from the service represents groups of people, then the code ought to say that too.  As an example, I've included a simple `Person` object who knows how to build itself from a flat representation and knows how to render itself on the console.  (2) **key ordering is not determined** in JS object.  To get values from specifically ordered keys, one must specify the ordering.  The person `print()` method does this with an array.

See it here, running on a subset of the data...

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/data.json", function(data) {
    print_items(data);
});

class Person {
    constructor(data) {
        this.id = Object.keys(data)[0];
        this.state = data[this.id][0];
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this.id);
        let displayKeys = ['name', 'registration_1', 'registration_2', 'week', 'half_term'];
        displayKeys.forEach(key => console.log(this.state[key]));
    }
    asTableRow() {
        let displayKeys = ['name', 'registration_1', 'registration_2', 'week', 'half_term'];
        let tds = displayKeys.map(key => `<td>${this.state[key]}</td>`);
        return `<tr>${tds}</tr>`;
    }
}

function print_items(data) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(groupKey => {
        let group = data[groupKey];
        Object.keys(group).forEach(personKey => {
            let person = new Person(group[personKey]);
            person.print();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works and makes a lot of sense. I just made a small edit to make it work with my localhost JSON file and I also made it a function.

Comment: I am having some trouble though. I'm not used to this formatting and I can't get it to work with what I'm actually trying to do. What I really needed it to do was to insert a row into a table for each person, and each row contains 6 cells (groupKey, name, registration_1, registration_2, week, half_term). I just don't understand your code enough to get it to work for that. The way I did it previously was like this: https://pastebin.com/B3gbUinm (I added an expected result). Sorry to ask for more help but I just don't know how to make your code do that.

Comment: This is a nice illustration why objects are good.  I added a method whereby the Person object can render itself as a table row.  I think you'll see from that how to get N rows from N people, and it ought to be straight forward to wrap that with a table tag.  (Note, a static method on People might be a good place for that.  Note also that the `displayKeys` might become a static method of its own.  It is useful for two instance methods, and will be useful for a "headerRow()` method.  I'll leave these as an exercise, because I have to be offline for about 12 hours, but can supply help later)

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the internal loop by looking at each key and passing the value only. Also I suggest pulling the `Object.keys(person).length` out of your for loop because it will process what the keys are on every loop. If you put them into a variable and reference that it avoids reassessing the keys.

```
    var groups = Object.keys(testData);
    for(var i = 0; i<groups.length; i++){
        var group = testData[groups[i]];
        for(var j = 0; j<group.length; j++){
            var personEntry = group[j];
            var person_id = Object.keys(personEntry)[0];
            console.log(person_id);
            var personEntries = personEntry[person_id];
            for(var k = 0; k<personEntries.length; k++){
                var personValues = Object.values(personEntries[k]);
                for(var l = 0; l<personValues.length; l++){
                    console.log(personValues[l]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like it's not working. It's just outputting "HA09_000" then "0: {name: "Wyatt Feldt", registration_1: "R", registration_2: "R", week: 0, half_term: 1}" for each person.

Comment: I see you edited your post, but now it prints "HA09_000" "H" "A" "0" "9".

Comment: I had to rework it because the previous structure wasn't easy to reason with. Try this out instead.

Comment: Thanks but this is the way of doing it I referenced in my question (requires an extra for loop). I'm sure there is way of doing it like I described in my Pseudo Code (i.e. 3 for loops).

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the properties of the object using a for/in loop.

I have added the for/in loop to your code (using the person_info object) and tested it and it is printing what you desire.
Hope this helps.

```
function output_json(data) {
    var i, j, k;
    for (i=0; i<Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        group_=Object.values(data)[i];
        for (j=0; j<Object.keys(group_).length; j++) {
            person=Object.values(group_)[j];
            person_id=Object.keys(person)[0];   
            console.log(person_id);
            for (k=0; k<Object.keys(person).length; k++) {
                person_info=Object.values(person)[k][0];
                //loop through the properties of the person_info object
                //using a for/in loop
                for (var key in person_info) {
                   console.log(person_info[key]); 
                }              
            }
        }
    }
}
```