# get object by key, keep key with it

Tags: javascript, json, key

I am filtering data that looks like below with `json[username]` for example.

data looks like:

```
{"albert":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}
{"sally":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}
{"petey":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}
{"gilbert":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}
```

so, for instance `json[sally]` brings in `sally` data but omits her name (the key) giving me the below:

```
{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}
```

I need to bring in/keep the name key as well. **i.e. the whole line:**

```
{"sally":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}
```

If I hardcode it:  `user = "{" + username + ":"+json[username]+"}";` the object stops working: consoles as just `{sally:[object Object]}`. Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: If `json[username]` works then `json` is an object and not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: You can't have a key outside an object.

Comment: Your output makes no sense, `key: value` on its own doesn't mean anything (it's a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)). Why not create an object that *also* includes the key, for example?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows what you've tried so far and the actual (but stripped down) input and output format. Right now this question doesn't make much sense (imho).

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the json and try it in this way,

```
for(let item in json){
    let data = {};
    data[item] = json[item];
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply loop over the data like so:

```
for(var key in data){
    console.log(key);
    console.log(data[key]);
}
```

here, key will store the name sally, while data stored in sally is extracted via data[key].

You can also refer this post: [How to loop through key/value object in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958841/how-to-loop-through-key-value-object-in-javascript)

Comment: That is a good way to get the key; but data still console logs as {"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}

Comment: need: {"sally":{"userCData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2",...................]}}

Comment: I just tried to hardcode it and the object stops reporting:                 userA = "{" + username + ":"+json[username]+"}";

Comment: try: console.dir(data); - where data is the json data.

Comment: what about: userA = ' "{" + username + ":"+json[username]+"}" '