# How to render array of objects with random key and values in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have following array of objects in React:

```
const arr = [
  { randomnumber: 'random string' },
  { randomnumber: 'random string' }
];
```

Where every number (key) and string (value) are always random. How to render this? I want to get something like this:

```
<p> {randomnumber} is: {randomstring} </p>
```

I've tried few methods with map, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us your attempts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through key/value object in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958841/how-to-loop-through-key-value-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each object has a single key/value pair, you can use the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) functions:

```
arr.map(obj => {
  const [key] = Object.keys(obj);
  const [value] = Object.values(obj);

  return (
    <p key={key}>
      {key} is: {value}
    </p>
  );
});
```