# How do I iterate over an enum without getting undefined for an enum key?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have created this enum:

```
export enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1 = 'brown',
    VALUE2 = 'green'
}
```

I would like to iterate over the enum for the purposes of building a select menu with the key being the value and the string being the label. But this code:

```
for (const key in Object.keys(MyEnum)) {
  console.log('value is');
  console.log((MyEnum as any)[key]);
}
```

produces an "undefined" when I try and look up an enum value by key.  What's the proper way to get the enum value by its key?

Comment: Is this a typo? Did you really intend to write `in Object.keys(MyEnum)` (keys of the keys?) instead of `of Object.keys(MyEnum)` or perhaps `in MyEnum`?

Comment: Or as you want both `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(MyEnum)) { }`. Specific problem is you're iterating over the _indexes_, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3010840/3001761 shows how to actually iterate over array values, but really you're just starting with an object `{ VALUE1: "brown", VALUE2: "green" }`, so maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/2958841/3001761.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `of` instead of `in`:

[typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=2#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gWAFBW1AagQQBkBVBARigF4oByAIwCcB7AdxBoBpMc8jSAmKrQDmDYKBqYAvpkwAzJgygAKAMZMQAZwAuUANbA4UJnKgB5OgCtgq7QDoDcTcvhJIASndR0WKOq1MADbAdoFMwso0AG4AhoFgwFAAlpo07gDc3H4amkEhYREuiMhQMZqlIHDuANqOALoZ0kA)

```
enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1 = 'brown',
    VALUE2 = 'green'
}

for (const key of Object.keys(MyEnum)) {
  console.log('value is');
  console.log((MyEnum as any)[key]);
}
```

As an aside, you can do

```
type MyEnumKey = keyof typeof MyEnum
for (const key of (Object.keys(MyEnum) as MyEnumKey[])) {
  console.log('value is');
  console.log(MyEnum[key]);
}
```